# Getting lift sources from maven repository

Tags: maven-2, scala, lift

I'm trying to learn how to use lift. I can create project skeleton by running maven commands (I had zero maven experience before) from [Starting with Lift](http://liftweb.net/docs/getting_started/mod_master.html). It successfully downloads needed dependencies and everything works fine, however it does not download sources - I'd like to see how lift works from inside.

Looks like it downloads dependencies from [here](http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/liftweb/lift-mapper/1.0/) and there are compiled .jar files as well as sources - there are **lift-mapper-1.0.jar** and **lift-mapper-1.0-sources.jar**, but only **lift-mapper-1.0.jar** is downloaded to my local repository. I could download sources manually, but there are more than just few folders there. So, is there a way to tell it to Maven to download dependencies with sources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) has a sources goal that will obtain the sources for all dependencies that are available. Simply run `mvn dependency:sources` to obtain the sources.

If you are using Eclipse, the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin handles source resolution and attachment for you. You can set it to automatically obtain sources in the Maven preferences. **Window** > **Preferences...**->**Maven**, then enable **Download Artifact Sources**.

You can also manually invoke "Download Sources" action from the Maven popup menu on any jars (including those that are not managed with Maven). Then plugin will use Maven repository indexes to lookup the corresponding Maven artifact and download its sources.

[image: download sources]